# java.awt.Shape is playing tricks on me

Tags: java, syntax, awt, draw, java-2d

![enter image description here][1]I'm in my first year of Java programming at school and I'm looking ahead in my book a little bit.  I've come across a class (called `Canvas`) that has a `draw(Shape shape)` method.

For some reason I can't figure out how to get any shapes to draw onto the canvas.  I've searched through the Java API and I can't get the syntax right. I'm pissed off because I know its something super simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code for the method that I'm stuck with:

```
/**
 * Draw the outline of a given shape onto the canvas.
 * @param  shape  the shape object to be drawn on the canvas
 */
public void draw(Shape shape)
{
    graphic.draw(shape);
    canvas.repaint();
}
```

When I call the method from the object it gives me something like this:

```
canvas1.draw(->Shape shape<-)
```

I've tried:

```
java.awt.Shape circle
java.awt.Shape Circle
Circle circle
Shape circle
```

The list goes on forever.

EDIT:

here's the meat and potatoes of the class... pretty straightfoward stuff

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

/**
 * Class Canvas - a class to allow for simple graphical 
 * drawing on a canvas.
 * 
 * @author Michael Kölling (mik)
 * @author Bruce Quig
 *
 * @version 2011.07.31
 */

public class Canvas
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private CanvasPane canvas;
    private Graphics2D graphic;
    private Color backgroundColor;
    private Image canvasImage;

    /**
     * Create a Canvas with default height, width and background color 
     * (300, 300, white).
     * @param title  title to appear in Canvas Frame     
     */
    public Canvas(String title)
    {
        this(title, 300, 300, Color.white);
    }

    /**
     * Create a Canvas with default background color (white).
     * @param title  title to appear in Canvas Frame
     * @param width  the desired width for the canvas
     * @param height  the desired height for the canvas
     */
    public Canvas(String title, int width, int height)
    {
        this(title, width, height, Color.white);
    }

    /**
     * Create a Canvas.
     * @param title  title to appear in Canvas Frame
     * @param width  the desired width for the canvas
     * @param height  the desired height for the canvas
     * @param bgClour  the desired background color of the canvas
     */
    public Canvas(String title, int width, int height, Color bgColor)
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        canvas = new CanvasPane();
        frame.setContentPane(canvas);
        frame.setTitle(title);
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        backgroundColor = bgColor;
        frame.pack();
        setVisible(true);
```

-- If I had enough rep to post a screen shot I would have --

Comment: Did you try calling the method without specifying the type? (`canvas.draw(circle)`, where `circle` is an instance of `Shape`)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: yea... tried that too

Comment: What does CanvasPane extend from?

Comment: ummm im assuming java.awt.*; imported the package...

Answer (score 2):

It might help to see more of your code, but I'm guessing from the fact that graphics is not a parameter, that you have somehow created a graphics object on your own. This tidbit from the javadoc for canvas should help you out:

> An application must subclass the Canvas class in order to get useful functionality such as creating a custom component.

I would normally expect to see you subclassing Canvas and then overriding `paint()` something like this...

```
public Class MyCanvas extends java.awt.Canvas {

  public void paint(Graphics g) {  
    super.paint(g);

    // some code to create the shape here... such as...
    // A rectangle with UL corner at 10,10, 30 wide, 50 high
    Shape myRectangle = new Rectangle2D.Float(10,10,30,50); 

    g.draw(myRectangle);

  }
}
```

This way you get the graphics object that belongs to the canvas, and draw the shape on to that. What I suspect you are doing is drawing it onto some other graphics object (not the one that belongs to the canvas). Usually this means that somewhere you've created an image, pulled a graphics object out of that and drawn into the image. But that image probably isn't getting drawn to any component... Hard to say for sure without more code.

You can put the canvas wherever you want in the UI just like any other component.

```
myFrame.add(new MyCanvas()); // example if you are adding it a frame called myFrame.
```

Java will call the paint method whenever ***Java*** decides it needs to redraw the MyCanvas object. You don't ever need to call paint.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I would normally expected to `super.paint(g)` and no `repaint` in a `paint` method

Comment: ... i added the fields and constructors to show you what the majority of the class looks like... so you're saying there's no 'java.awt.Shape' type of thing that creates shapes?  There's a similar method that asked for a specific color for the draw method and all I had to do was input 'java.awt.Color.RED' and I didn't receive any error.

Comment: Shape is an interface. It is implemented by many objects, including Rectangle2D, Arc2D, Polygon, etc. Create which ever one of those you want with something like new `Rectangle2D.Float(x,y,w,h)` I'm not sure where you found this Canvas class, but I don't like it. Learn to use the java.awt.Canvas class instead. (Which is what i thought you were using before). I see CanvasPane, which is apparently a BlueJ class. Learn to use the standard Java classes if you can, since that's what you will use if you ever get a job, not BlueJ.

Comment: @MadProgrammer True, though since canvas has no rendered UI of it's own, and we are not yet animating things the call to super not matter for this example. I suppose I'll add it for good form though.

Comment: super.paint does a LOT of important work, namely preparing the graphics context for painting. Graphics is a apshared resource, all components that are been painted during this paint cycle will use the same graphics context. Failure to call super.paint will result in painting artefacts been rendered, which is undesirable, animated or not

Comment: seems like this program has a lot of blueJ shortcuts... i kind of purposefully struggled with this program to force myself to use the API and stuff... but if im working with packages ill never use again ill just switch it... we do a lot of things in class that won't ever convert to a realistic situation... but thats school for you i guess

- thanks for the help guys

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hmm, was not aware of that. Pretty sure I've always called it in my code, but it's been years since I've done awt graphics now so I forgot here :). Also figured it might distract if the poster is not yet aware of or fully understanding the meaning of `super.`

Answer (score 0):

Use, for example:

```
    drawShape(new java.awt.Rectangle(10, 10, 40, 40))
```

where a paramenter to pass in Bluej Method Call Window is

```
    new java.awt.Rectangle(10, 10, 40, 40)
```